# If ViewBinding and GoogleMap are used together, an error will occur

Tags: android, kotlin

class

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    var viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWTpJ.png)

If you write ViewBinding and GoogleMap together, an error will occur. If you delete ViewBinding, no error will occur. What's the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you are supposed to do ViewBinding with an Activity:

> ````
> private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding
>
> override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>     binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
>     val view = binding.root
>     setContentView(view) } ```
> ````

As you can see, the resource id of the layout is not used, but the view from the binding instead.

source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

And then how you set the SupportMapFragment into the xml:

> ```
>  <fragment
>     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
> ```

Using `class` instead of `android:name`

source: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

There is nothing wrong with having SupportMapFragment and ViewBinding together.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
> ```

should be

```
val viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(viewBinding.root)
```